# Pivot rows into columns being the new ones booleans

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having a hard time trying out to pivot rows from a table into columns, yet I would need these new columns to be booleans letting us know if a record meets or not each one of the unique values of the pivoting column.

In a nutshell, what I need is to take a data frame like this one below:

```
id        colour
1         blue
1         blue
2         green
2         blue
2         black
3         blue
3         blue
4         green
```

And reshape like it follows:

```
id        blue     green     black
1         1        0         0
2         1        1         1
3         1        0         0
4         0        1         0
```

Is there a simple way to get this outcome?

Comment: Do you know the values for the pivot column in advance or are the values, and columns created from them dynamic?

Comment: In this particular case I know them on advance, yet a dynamic solution would be even more appreciated cause they might vary in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works if the values for colour are known/static.

Create the test data.

```
create or replace table unpivoted_data as 
select
id, 
colour
from (
    values(1 ,'BLUE'),
          (1,'BLUE'),
          (2,'GREEN'),
          (2,'BLUE'),
          (2,'BLACK'),
          (3,'BLUE'),
          (3,'BLUE'),
          (4,'GREEN')) 
    as t (id,colour);
```

Unpivot in CTE, and then treat pivoted values.

```
with T as (
    select ID, "'BLUE'" BLUE, "'GREEN'" GREEN, "'BLACK'" BLACK
    from 
        UNPIVOTED_DATA 
            pivot(max(COLOUR) for COLOUR in ('BLUE','GREEN','BLACK') ) as p)
select
    ID,
    IFF(BLUE IS NULL, 0,1) BLUE,
    IFF(GREEN IS NULL, 0,1) GREEN,
    IFF(BLACK IS NULL, 0,1) BLACK
from T;
```